# How to take a sample from a large plot to show in knitr-PDF

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, pheatmap

I often create large plots in RStudio which I save to PDF but would also like to partly show in the PDF knitr report.
Is there a way to create the full object then cut a piece (ideally top left corner) and include that second picture in the PDF report?

as example, a pheatmap code that produces a plot with 56 cols and 100's of rows. I would like to show only the left-top-most 10col and 10 rows but if I sample the input data, I obviously get another plot due to the clustering being done on different data. Also, I would love a solution applicable to any plot types (not only pheatmap).

```
drows <- "euclidean"
dcols <- "euclidean"
clustmet <- "complete"

col.pal <- c("lightgrey","blue")

main.title <- paste("Variant (freq>", minfreq, "%) in all samples", sep="") 

hm.parameters.maj <- list(hm.maj.data, 
                      color = col.pal,
                      fontsize = 10,
                      cellwidth = 14, 
                      cellheight = 14, 
                      scale = "none",
                      treeheight_row = 200,
                      kmeans_k = NA,
                      show_rownames = T, 
                      show_colnames = T,
                      main = main.title,
                      clustering_method = clustmet,
                      cluster_rows = TRUE, 
                      cluster_cols = FALSE,
                      clustering_distance_rows = drows, 
                      clustering_distance_cols = dcols,
                      legend=FALSE)

# To draw the heatmap on screen (comment-out if you run the script from terminal)
do.call("pheatmap", hm.parameters.maj)

# To draw to file (you may want to adapt the info(header(vcf))sizes)
outfile <- paste("major-variants_heatmap_(freq>", minfreq, ")_", drows, ".pdf", sep="")
do.call("pheatmap", c(hm.parameters.maj, filename=outfile, width=24, height=35))
```

Thanks in advance
Stephane

Comment: Just an idea for the right approach: Executing the code `myObject <- do.call("pheatmap", hm.parameters.maj)` will give you a well-structured object. When you call `str(myObject)` in the console, you will see that there is an attribute called `myObject$gtable` which seems to contain all the information you need when you want to create your modified output.

Comment: Here is how to work with gtables like the ones you have there: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtable/gtable.pdf

Comment: Thanks @nisole, this sounds indeed very right. I look into it asap.